# Array of objects pointing to different instances of the class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a class Geometry. In another class, I want to create an array of instances of Geometry and refer to them.

```
class Geometry {

    private static int edges[];
    private static int vertices[];
    private static sphere();
    private static circle();  
}

class Example {

    Geometry [] Shape = new Geometry [5];
    public draw(){
        Shape[0] = new Geometry();
        Shape[1] = new Geometry();
        Shape[0].circle();
        Shape[1].sphere();

        <code to draw shape for Shape[i]>
    }
}
```

`Sphere()` and `Circle()` initialize the edges and vertices differently. I want Shape[0] to have its edges and vertices assigned values for a circle, and Shape[1] for a sphere. When I iterate through each object in the draw function, it should draw a Circle and then a sphere, instead of 2 spheres as it is currently doing.

Comment: bud there is a concept of iterating through Objects. Consider examples on For loop to start with the most simplistic approach

Comment: The code you have provided does not demonstrate the problem you are having.  Instead, please try to provide a [SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Compilable Example)](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your Geometry state is static, which means its shared between all instances of that class. Fix that and your code should work.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!

Comment: your design is not following OOP principles :) .. would suggest some improvements if you would want suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You have one single class and no virtual functions; so this not really an Object Oriented code.  Instead, try something like:

```
abstract class Geometry {
    private int edges[];
    private int vertices[];
    abstract void draw();
}

class Circle extends Geometry {
    void draw() {
       // Code to draw a circle here.
    }
}

class Sphere extends Geometry {
    void draw() {
       // Code to draw a shere here.
    }
}

class Example {

    Geometry [] shape = new Geometry [5];
    public draw() {
        shape[0] = new Circle();
        shape[1] = new Sphere();
        shape[0].draw(); // Will draw a circle.
        shape[1].draw(); // Will draw a sphere.
    }
}
```

For this example, the function Geometry.draw() is empty but it's quite possible that you will want to put something there and even call this function from the subclasses:

```
class Geometry {
    ...
    draw() { DoSomethingUseful(); }
}

class Circle extends Geometry {
    draw() {
       super.draw();
       // Remaining of the code to draw a circle here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Polymorphism`.

```
abstract class Geometry {

    private int edges[];
    private int vertices[];
    abstract void setdata();//Geometry class won't define this method, the classes deriving it must define it
    abstract void paintShape(Graphics graphics);//Geometry class won't define this method, the classes deriving it must define it  
}
class Circle extends Geometry
{
    public void paintShape(Graphics graphics)
    {
       //code to paint the circle
    }
    public void setdata()
    {
       //code to set the vertices and edges for a circle
    }
}
class Sphere extends Geometry
{
    public void paintShape(Graphics graphics)
    {
       //code to paint the sphere
    }
    public void setdata()
    {
       //code to set the vertices and edges for a sphere
    }
}
```

My comments gives almost all explanations you may need.
And while you want to paint these.

```
class Example {

    Geometry [] Shape = new Geometry [5];
    public draw(){
        Shape[0] = new Circle();
        Shape[1] = new Shape();
        Shape[0].setdata();
        Shape[1].setdata();

        //code to draw shape for Shape[i]
        Shape[0].draw(panel.getGraphics());
        Shape[1].draw(panel.getGraphics());
    }
}
```